# display a csv file in LaTeX

Tags: tables, datatool, csv, excel

How can I link a `csv` file, and display the data in separate columns ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTUoaddb[keys=c1,c2,c3]{ctext}{csvtext.csv}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{clr}
\textbf{Software} & \textbf{Manufacturer} &
\textbf{Malware}
\DTLforeach{ctext}{
    \cola=c1, \colb=c2, \colc=c3}{
\\
    \cola & \colb & \colc}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: the excell file]

### Edit : Clarification

Can I import data from the normal Excel file without placing the data in a row in the Excel file

[image: the excell file]
[image: the excell file]

Comment: I tried to link the columns where the data is in table form in the latex but the result was that I did not get a table that prints the data

Comment: Can you post the relevant `.csv` file?

Comment: [To export to `csv` from excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jW_ZJpVy_0)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really about spreadsheet export.

Comment: ... or spreadsheet import. Ali, you should open your file with Excel choosing "file delemited by" and set delimiter=, in the dialog boxes that appear, see here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba This question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

## With a lot of lines

per request

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{csvtext.csv}
Software,Manuf,Mal
323,lkj,jjkl
345,jk,asdf
455,kjafs,ssd
\end{filecontents*}
\DTLloaddb[keys={c1,c2,c3}]{ctext}{csvtext.csv}
\begin{document}
~
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Software} & \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Malware} 
    \DTLforeach{ctext}
    {\cola=c1, \colb=c2, \colc=c3}
    {\cr\hline \cola & \colb & \colc}
    \cr \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

## Original answer

It seems to work fine, modulo some typos.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{csvtext.csv}
Software,Manuf,Mal
323,lkj,jjkl
345,jk,asdf
455,kjafs,ssd
\end{filecontents*}
\DTLloaddb[keys={c1,c2,c3}]{ctext}{csvtext.csv}
\begin{document}
~
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{clr}
    \textbf{Software} & \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Malware} \\
    \DTLforeach{ctext}
    {\cola=c1, \colb=c2, \colc=c3}
    {
      \\
      \cola & \colb & \colc
    }
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not what you requested to do the process of linking the data from the Excel file and the data exists as it is in the default Excel columns

Comment: @ali Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Please be more explicit as to what you want.

Comment: Can we link the data in the Excel file as it is in the columns (to put between the data a chapter mark (,) because many of the tables in which we use the data are placed in separate columns rather than in a single column separated by the chapter mark (,)                      I put the picture of the Excel file and the data in it as illustrated and I want to make the latex table of this data located in several columns and not one column

Comment: @ali Sorry, I don't understand. Please edit your question and add a picture to show the exact output you want.

Comment: @ali So you want vertical lines between columns ?

Comment: I've seen an example of YouTube in which an Excel file is linked without putting data in a row separated by a tag,

Comment: have difficulty with English so I hope you give me your precious time so I can deliver my idea

Comment: Can I import data from the normal Excel file without placing the data in a one row in the Excel file

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want. Can you post an internet link, or maybe ask your question in French, if it is easier ?

Comment: The title of YouTube is the following "How to create tables from external files Excel or others using Latex.avi" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwdGRbCp2yU

Comment: I put the pictures you asked in the ad to know what I mean

Comment: @ali Follow this [To export to csv from excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jW_ZJpVy_0), make sure you use the good delimiters `,` when you are saving from excel.

Comment: Preserving the data in the Excel table as it is when linked with latex rather than placing it in a row inside the Excel as in the two images above shows this with the correct selection mark